# Pasting text in vim. A tedious operation?

Tags: vim, insert, space, paste, yank

I've been using vim for somewhat longer than a year now and during this time I have never feel really comfortable with the way vim works with yanking and pasting text (or maybe it is just me not using it in the most efficient way)

For example, I have the word "World" yanked onto a register, and I want to paste it after "Hello". (Note that there are no spaces on either of the words). So, what I would do is

```
Hello
    |
```

Place cursor here, and press "p". Then, what I will end up with is

```
HelloWorld
```

So, in order to avoid this, I have always to swith into insert mode, insert a espace, and go back into normal mode (or either make sure that the yanked word has a space before it). Be as it may, this is quite annoying behaviour I can't think of a solution for... Am I missing something here?

Suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I would be pretty upset if my editor took the liberty of inserting whitespace arbitrarily upon pasting. In insert mode you can do `<C-r>"` to paste.

Comment: Thanks romainl for your answer. I didn't mean for the editor to insert the spaces automatically, but I guess to have an option to move to the right of some word (the editor will assume there is an space there) and then paste the word there. Regarding the CTRL + R, yes, it is an option, although I do not think it is the way to go, given that I intend to paste in normal mode and not in insert mode (plus I do not  see it very convenient the CTRL + R + <register> combo ...)

Comment: @romainl Wow, after all this time I didn't realise, and it makes so much sense! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**option zero**

just live with what you have now.

**option one**

create a mapping for your workflow. for example

```
nnoremap <leader>p i<space><esc>p
```

**option two**

```
:set ve=all
```

then you could move your cursor to anywhere and paste

**option three**

you could in insert mode use `<c-o>` do normal mode stuff or `<c-r>` to get register values

I recommend **option zero**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Smartput : Adjust spaces and commas when putting text plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2095) for that. It modifies the `p` / `P` commands (this can be toggled on / off).